# Quasar boot file and authentincation

Tags: javascript, authentication, vue-router, quasar-framework

I'm using Quasar for my app and it uses SSR and PWA.

I'm trying to have the User logged in if the Token in the cookies is still valid and I added a middleware to the various routes to block access if not authenticated.

So I first created a boot file:

```
export default boot(async ({ ssrContext, store }) => {
  const checkAuthStatus = async () => {
    const cookies = process.env.SERVER ? Cookies.parseSSR(ssrContext) : Cookies;
    const token = cookies.get(`${cookieDomain}.token`);
    const expires = cookies.get(`${cookieDomain}.expires`);
    const isNotExpired = moment(expires).utc().isAfter(moment.utc());

    if (token && isNotExpired) {
      try {
        const authStore = useAuthStore(store);
        // The file reaches this line.
        await authStore.setSession();
        // The file DOESN'T reaches this line but the setSession is correctly called and executed.
      } catch (error) {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  await checkAuthStatus();
});
```

The `setSession` action perform a get User from the API and set a property called `isAuthenticated` to `true`.

In my routes I have this:

```
import authenticated from "src/middlewares/authenticated";
...
{
  path: "feeds",
  name: "feeds",
  component: () => import("pages/FeedsPage.vue"),
  meta: {
    middleware: [authenticated],
  },
},
```

The Middleware "authenticated" is pretty straight forward:

```
import { useAuthStore } from "src/stores/auth";

export default function authenticated({ next }) {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuthStore();

  // isAuthenticated is always false on page refresh, even if it is set to true from the setSession action in the boot file

  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return next({ name: "login" });
  }

  return next();
}
```

I will not write here the logic to handle the middleware in the Routes, that part is working fine.

What is not clear to me is why Quasar initializes the Routes before the Boot files.

When the application starts I expect the boot files to run before everything else. Instead, the logic works fine until it reaches the middleware that is initialized before the boot file, so it returns false by default, blocking the user from accessing a restricted page.

Probably it is me missing something to have this working as expected. Here I need your hint. The only solution I see, at the moment, is to move the boot logic in the middleware, but in that case, it would run every time I change the route, and it is not necessary...

PS.: This works fine in SPA mode, only when I switch to SSR it starts to fail.

I hope it makes sense.